# Is there a way to load Django template modules from code instead of templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

For example we need to have this `{% load staticfiles %}` in the template to be able to use static files.

Is there a way to configure Django to load this from the code instead?

**LE:** Sorry for not being clear. I don't need to actually use this in the code. I just want django to load this automatically, so it's available in the templates without me actually adding this tag at the top of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undocumented feature but it works:

```
from django.template import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.static')
```

The code above is for django 1.7.  For previous version of django you should import `add_to_builtins` from `django.template.loader`.